# pydantic How to set hex string to int using pydantic?

Tags: python, initialization, getter-setter, pydantic

Sometimes, any data return a hex string like "bbb". I wanna use to int value by "bbb".
So I wrote code case1.. but it is an error.

How to convert hex string to int value using BaseModel?
Does pydantic also have a setter getter function?
I know a method like case2, but I wanna use a json data directly, because of some key is empty...!

### case 1

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

data = {
    "aaa" : 4,
    "bbb" : "0x3",
}

class DataTemp(BaseModel):
    aaa : int
    bbb : Optional[int]
    
def main():
    _data = DataTemp(**data)
    print(_data)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### case2

```
_data2 = DataTemp(aaa= data["aaa"], bbb=int(data["bbb"],16))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>This answer has been updated for Pydantic V2 (specifically 2.5.x) as per the [this section of their migration guide](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/migration/#changes-to-validators) while maintaining the original intent of [this prior revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72554268/2).</sub>

---

Pydantic does allow the attachment of additional validators to a given field by via [field validators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/#field-validators).  When creating one you will need to take care to deal with the incoming data and process it based on your requirements.  In your example, it should allow `None`, standard `int`s and also any `str` that represent a hexadecimal string.  So the following implementation can satisfy the mentioned constraints:

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationInfo, field_validator

class DataTemp(BaseModel):
    aaa: int
    # to allow the assignment of str along with int, even though the
    # value will always be casted back to an int via the field validator,
    # and set the default value to None to permit omitted key in V2
    bbb: Optional[int | str] = None

    @field_validator('bbb')
    @classmethod
    def validate_bbb(cls, v: Optional[int | str], info: ValidationInfo):
        return int(v, 16) if isinstance(v, str) else v
```

Usage:

```
>>> DataTemp(aaa=4, bbb=33)
DataTemp(aaa=4, bbb=33)
>>> DataTemp(aaa=4, bbb=None)
DataTemp(aaa=4, bbb=None)
>>> DataTemp(aaa=4)  # bbb omitted, defaults to None as specified
DataTemp(aaa=4, bbb=None)
>>> DataTemp(aaa=4, bbb='0x333')
DataTemp(aaa=4, bbb=819)
>>> DataTemp(aaa=4, bbb='32')
DataTemp(aaa=4, bbb=50)
>>> DataTemp(aaa=4, bbb='asdf')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 164, in __init__
    __pydantic_self__.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=__pydantic_self__)
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for DataTemp
bbb
  Value error, invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'asdf' [type=value_error, input_value='asdf', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/value_error
```

Comment: Wow! It's what I wanted! thank you!